# Spring MVC is truncating JSP View

Tags: java, html, spring

I am a new bee in SPRING MVC, I decided to build a project so as to get familiar with the Framework, everything is going on fine except if the HTML tags are much, it truncates them. I don't know why Thanks

This is the JSP Code

```
<%@ page language = "java" contentType = "text/html ; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding = "UTF-8"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">-->

<title>Ilanaa</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- SmartAdmin Styles : Please note (smartadmin-production.css) was created using LESS variables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/smartadmin-production.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/favicon/favicon.ico"
    type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/favicon/favicon.ico"
    type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/splash/sptouch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plugins/video/video-js.min.css"
    type="text/css" />
<style>
.search-results {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 19px;
}

aside #left-panel {
    position: static;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="minified" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <header id="header">
        <div id="logo-group">
            <span id="logo"> <img
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/logo.png"
                alt="SmartAdmin">
            </span> <span id="activity" class="activity-dropdown"> <i
                class="fa fa-user"></i> <b class="badge"> 21 </b>
            </span>

            <div class="ajax-dropdown">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/mail.html"> Msgs (14)
                    </label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/notifications.html">
                        notify (3)
                    </label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/tasks.html"> Tasks (4)
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ajax-notifications custom-scroll">

                    <div class="alert alert-transparent">
                        <h4>Click a button to show messages here</h4>
                        This blank page message helps protect your privacy, or you can
                        show the first message here automatically.
                    </div>

                    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-4x fa-border"></i>

                </div>
                <span> Last updated on: 12/12/2013 9:43AM
                    <button type="button"
                        data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i> Loading..."
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
                <!-- end footer -->

            </div>
            <!-- END AJAX-DROPDOWN -->
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <!-- projects dropdown -->
        <div id="project-context">

            <span class="label">Projects:</span> <span id="project-selector"
                class="popover-trigger-element dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">Recent projects <i
                class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>

            <!-- Suggestion: populate this list with fetch and push technique -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Online e-merchant
                        management system - attaching integration with the iOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Notes on pipeline
                        upgradee</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Assesment Report for
                        merchant account</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i
                        class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Clear</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end dropdown-menu-->

        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div style="margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a href="login.html" title="Inform the world"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#myModal"><i class ="fa fa-stack-o"></i>Add Stack</a> <a href="login.html"
                    title="Inform the world" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Sign
                    In <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- end pulled right: nav area -->

    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
    <aside id="left-panel">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>

        <!-- User info -->
        <div class="login-info">
            <span> <!-- User image size is adjusted inside CSS, it should stay as it -->

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show-shortcut"> <img
                    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/avatars/sunny.png"
                    alt="me" class="online" /> <span> john.doe </span> <i
                    class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </a>

            </span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="index.html" title="Dashboard"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/inbox.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-inbox"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Inbox</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/notification.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Notification</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/activities.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-list"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Activities</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/logout.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Logout</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-file"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Other Pages</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ajax/forum.html">Forum Layout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <span class="minifyme"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i>
        </span>

    </aside>
    <!-- MAIN PANEL -->

    <c:import url = "add_stack.jsp"></c:import>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            document
                    .write('<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>

    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
            document
                    .write('<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/SmartNotification.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jarvis.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.easy-pie-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery.mb.browser.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plugins/video/video.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/demo.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the result i get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">-->

<title>Ilanaa</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- SmartAdmin Styles : Please note (smartadmin-production.css) was created using LESS variables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/css/smartadmin-production.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/img/favicon/favicon.ico"
    type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/img/favicon/favicon.ico"
    type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/img/splash/sptouch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/Ilanaa/resources/plugins/video/video-js.min.css"
    type="text/css" />
<style>
.search-results {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 19px;
}

aside #left-panel {
    position: static;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="minified" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <header id="header">
        <div id="logo-group">
            <span id="logo"> <img
                src="/Ilanaa/resources/img/logo.png"
                alt="SmartAdmin">
            </span> <span id="activity" class="activity-dropdown"> <i
                class="fa fa-user"></i> <b class="badge"> 21 </b>
            </span>

            <div class="ajax-dropdown">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/mail.html"> Msgs (14)
                    </label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/notifications.html">
                        notify (3)
                    </label> <label class="btn btn-default"> <input type="radio"
                        name="activity" id="ajax/notify/tasks.html"> Tasks (4)
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="ajax-notifications custom-scroll">

                    <div class="alert alert-transparent">
                        <h4>Click a button to show messages here</h4>
                        This blank page message helps protect your privacy, or you can
                        show the first message here automatically.
                    </div>

                    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-4x fa-border"></i>

                </div>
                <span> Last updated on: 12/12/2013 9:43AM
                    <button type="button"
                        data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i> Loading..."
                        class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
                <!-- end footer -->

            </div>
            <!-- END AJAX-DROPDOWN -->
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <!-- projects dropdown -->
        <div id="project-context">

            <span class="label">Projects:</span> <span id="project-selector"
                class="popover-trigger-element dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown">Recent projects <i
                class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>

            <!-- Suggestion: populate this list with fetch and push technique -->
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Online e-merchant
                        management system - attaching integration with the iOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Notes on pipeline
                        upgradee</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Assesment Report for
                        merchant account</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i
                        class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Clear</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end dropdown-menu-->

        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div style="margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a href="login.html" title="Inform the world"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#myModal"><i class ="fa fa-stack-o"></i>Add Stack</a> <a href="login.html"
                    title="Inform the world" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> Sign
                    In <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- end pulled right: nav area -->

    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
    <aside id="left-panel">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>

        <!-- User info -->
        <div class="login-info">
            <span> <!-- User image size is adjusted inside CSS, it should stay as it -->

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show-shortcut"> <img
                    src="/Ilanaa/resources/img/avatars/sunny.png"
                    alt="me" class="online" /> <span> john.doe </span> <i
                    class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </a>

            </span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="index.html" title="Dashboard"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/inbox.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-inbox"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Inbox</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/notification.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Notification</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/activities.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-list"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Activities</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/logout.html"><i
                        class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Logout</span><span
                        class="badge pull-right inbox-badge">14</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-file"></i> <span
                        class="menu-item-parent">Other Pages</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ajax/forum.html">Forum Layout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <span class="minifyme"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i>
        </span>

    </aside>
    <!-- MAIN PANEL -->


  <modal>
            <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                 aria-hidden="false">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                ×
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <img src="img/logo.png" width="150" alt="SmartAdmin">
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body no-padding">

                            <ul id="writeTab" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#w1" data-toggle="tab">Create a New Project</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="pull-right hidden-mobile">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"> <span
                                            class="note">About 24,431 activities since last login </span> </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div id="writeTab" class="tab-content bg-color-white padding-10">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="w1">
                                    <form action="" id="new-project" class="smart-form" name = "project-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "post">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <section>
                                                <label class="input">
```

Note: the HTML tags are truncated.

Comment: Please post some code, you have not given us enough to go on in your question. You can start with posting your jsp.

Comment: You should provide an example, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you with this little information.

Comment: This site doesn't have magicians which will visualize your code ;-)

Comment: You're not even including the relevant code, the "About XYZ activities since last login" text is nowhere to be found in the JSP you pasted.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying @kryger. Should I put d codes that are in the controller?

Comment: No. Looks like your problem is in **add_stack.jsp**, not the bit you included. You can see this by analysing where the `MAIN PANEL` bit comes from. To narrow it down you'll need the Jasper JSP compilation log.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with JSP-using web apps (Struts and a little Spring), when the page is truncated it is usually because an error occurred in the middle of rendering it. Often it stops quite a ways before the error because the page render only flushes output every so often. But you can be sure the error (at least the one stopping the page render) is somewhere after the last part in the output

So first, check for an exception + stack trace in the logs. Then use the info in the stack trace or error message to track down the problem.

If you don't find an exception, you're gonna have a much harder time tracking down the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but the error was before the last part in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to see what the error was, after so much debugging.

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                ×
                            </button>
```

see the 'x' in the button tag is a special character, that's why the view was trucated.

The truncatation happens after the error

Thanks.